# Parse Text File, Group rows based on Text string marker

Tags: t-sql

I am importing a large text file that consists of several 'reports'. Each report consists of several rows of data. The only way I know when a new report starts is the line starts with "XX". Then all rows following belong to that master row with XX. I am trying to put in a grouping ID so that I can work with the data and parse it into the database.

```
CREATE TABLE RawData(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,Grp1 int NULL
    ,Grp2 int NULL
    ,Rowdata varchar(max) NULL
)

INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'XX Monday'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'Tues day'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'We d ne s day'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'Thurs day'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'F r i d day'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'XX January'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'Feb r u a'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'XX Sun d a y'
INSERT INTO RawData(Rowdata) VALUES 'Sat ur day'
```

I need to write a script that will update the Grp1 field based on where the "XX" line is at. When I am finished I'd like the table to look like this:

```
ID   Grp1   Grp2   RowData
1    1      1      XX Monday
2    1      2      Tues day
3    1      3      We d ne s day
4    1      4      Thurs day
5    1      5      F r i d day
6    2      1      XX January
7    2      2      Feb r u a
8    3      1      XX Sun d a y
9    3      2      Sat ur day
```

I know for Grp2 field I can use the DENSE_RANK. The issue I am having is how do I fill in all the values for Grp1. I can do an update where I see the 'XX', but that does not fill in the values below.

Thank you for any advise/help.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @RawData TABLE 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,Grp1 int NULL
    ,Grp2 int NULL
    ,Rowdata varchar(max) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @RawData(Rowdata) 
VALUES ('XX Monday'),('Tues day'),('We d ne s day'),('Thurs day'),('F r i d day'),
       ('XX January'),('Feb r u a'),('XX Sun d a y'),('Sat ur day');

-- solution
WITH rr AS
(
  SELECT ID, thisVal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM @rawData
  WHERE RowData LIKE 'XX %'
),
makeGrp1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID,
    Grp1 = (SELECT MAX(thisVal) FROM rr WHERE r.id >= rr.id),
    RowData
  FROM @rawData r
)
SELECT 
  ID,
  Grp1,
  Grp2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp1 ORDER BY ID),
  RowData
FROM makeGrp1;
```

***UPDATE:*** below is the code to update you @RawData table; I just re-read the requirement. I'm leaving the original solution as it will help you bbetter understand how my update works:

```
-- sample data
DECLARE @RawData TABLE 
(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,Grp1 int NULL
    ,Grp2 int NULL
    ,Rowdata varchar(max) NULL
);
INSERT INTO @RawData(Rowdata) 
VALUES ('XX Monday'),('Tues day'),('We d ne s day'),('Thurs day'),('F r i d day'),
       ('XX January'),('Feb r u a'),('XX Sun d a y'),('Sat ur day');

-- Solution to update the @RawData Table
WITH rr AS
(
  SELECT ID, thisVal = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM @rawData
  WHERE RowData LIKE 'XX %'
),
makeGroups AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID,
    Grp1 = (SELECT MAX(thisVal) FROM rr WHERE r.id >= rr.id),
    Grp2 = ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT MAX(thisVal) FROM rr WHERE r.id >= rr.id) ORDER BY ID)
  FROM @rawData r
)
UPDATE @RawData 
SET Grp1 = mg.Grp1, Grp2 = mg.Grp2
FROM makeGroups mg
JOIN @RawData rd ON mg.ID = rd.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte0 as (
    Select *,Flag = case when RowData like 'XX%' then 1 else 0 end
    From   RawData )
Update RawData
   Set Grp1 = B.Grp1
      ,Grp2 = B.Grp2
 From RawData U
 Join (
        Select ID
              ,Grp1 = Sum(Flag) over (Order by ID)
              ,Grp2 = Row_Number() over (Partition By (Select Sum(Flag) From cte0 Where ID<=a.ID) Order by ID)
         From cte0 A
      ) B on U.ID=B.ID

Select * from RawData
```

The Updated RawData looks like this

[image]

Comment: Well done John - this is a pretty efficient solution. One minor correction:
in your SET statement, instead of Grp2 = B.Grp1 you wanted Grp2 = B.Grp2.

Comment: @JJones Happy to help.